# How can i apply a color= argument to all plots in a dropdown menu

Tags: python, plot, plotly

How can i apply the **color = 'sex'** argument to all the plots?  it's only working on the first (G1 G2 G3) plot now... When I select G2/G3 from the dropdown menu the boxplot won't show the 'sex' from the dataframe.

```
dropdown_buttons = [{'label':'G1, G2, G3', 'method': 'update',
                 'args':[{'visible': [True, True, True]},
                        {'title': 'G1, G2, G3'}]},
                {'label':'G1', 'method': 'update',
                 'args':[{'visible': [True, False, False]},
                        {'title': 'G1'}]},
               {'label':'G2', 'method': 'update',
                 'args':[{'visible': [False, True, False]},
                        {'title': 'G2'}]},
               {'label':'G3', 'method': 'update',
                 'args':[{'visible': [False, False, True]},
                        {'title': 'G3'}]},
               ]

fig5 = go.Figure(px.box(students, x='age', y=['G1', 'G2', 'G3'], color = 'sex',
                   labels = {'age': 'Age', 'G3': 'G3', 'sex': 'Sex'}))

fig5.update_layout({'updatemenus':[{'type': "dropdown",
                              'x': 1.3,
                              'y': 0.5,
                              'showactive': True,
                              'active': 0,
                              'buttons': dropdown_buttons}]})

fig5.show()
```

[image: Working plot, color is defined by 'sex' from a dataframe]

Comment: Could you please provide us with dummy data for students table?

Comment: The best solution to solve it is to use go.Box for each G. The problem will be solved accordingly.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example